# Как автоматизировать процедуру на Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Есть процедура, которая очень плохо написана:

```
procedure PrintLeftPartOfDiamond(k, n : integer);
begin
   if (k = 1) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n + 1);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 2) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 1);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 3) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 3);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 4) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 5);
      write('*');
   end
end;
```

Не пойму, как её сделать нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Весь код выглядит так:

```
program diamonds;
procedure PrintChars(ch : char; count : integer);
var i : integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to count do
      write(ch)
end;

procedure PrintLeftPartOfDiamond(k, n : integer);
begin
   if (k = 1) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n + 1);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 2) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 1);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 3) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 3);
      write('*');
   end;
   if (k = 4) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*n - 5);
      write('*');
   end
end;

procedure PrintRightPartOfDiamond(k : integer );
begin
   if k > 1 then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2*k -3);
      write('*');
   end
end;

procedure PrintLineOfDiamonds(k, n, count : integer);
var i : integer;
begin
   i := 0;
   PrintChars(' ' , n + 1 - k);
   write('*');
   if (k > 1)  then 
   begin   
      PrintRightPartOfDiamond(k);
   end;   
   while i < count - 1 do begin
      PrintLeftPartOfDiamond(k, n);
      PrintRightPartOfDiamond(k);
      i := i + 1;
   end;
   writeln
end;

var n, k, h, count : integer;
begin
   repeat
      write('Enter the diamond''s height (positive odd): ');
      read(h);
      write('Enter the count of diamonds: ');
      read(count);
   until (h > 0) and (h mod 2 = 1);
   n := h div 2;
   for k := 1 to n + 1 do
      PrintLineOfDiamonds(k, n, count);
   for k := n downto 1 do
      PrintLineOfDiamonds(k, n, count)
end.
```

Он выводит такую фигуру, пользователь задаёт размер и количество двумя параметрами:

```
  *     *     *
 * *   * *   * *
*   * *   * *   *
 * *   * *   * *
  *     *     *
```

Comment: Околодубликат - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1446458

Answer (score 3):

Если вы всё еще про "сократить код" то можно так сделать:

```
const
  POSITION: array [1..4] of Integer = (1, -1, -3, -5);

procedure PrintLeftPartOfDiamond(k, n: integer);
begin
   if (k >= 1) and (k <= 4) then
   begin
      PrintChars(' ', 2 * n - POSITION[k]);
      write('*');
   end
end;
```

Comment: @Kromster, можно и так, но кмк - моветон объявлять массивы с еденицы, даже если хочется :)

Comment: Согласен. Но изменять переданный аргумент в теле метода тоже моветон =) Так то нумерацию строк с 1 ТС предложил. Ему тогда в других местах код тоже менять придется.

Comment: Он передан не по ссылке, ничего ему не будет, integer передается по умолчанию по значению :) ну и можно записать всегда как POSITION[k-1]

Comment: Именно так, поэтому и "моветон", а не "опасная ошибка" ;-)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Интересное решение, но тут, ещё вот в чём дело. Если сделать фигуру большего размера она не прорисуется, т.к значения POSITION в ручную прописаны. И ограничены массивом. Это на максимум размер 7 от вводимого. Их надо как-то связать с вводимым значением.

Comment: Кстати про нумерацию строк - она по умолчанию в паскале в отличии от массива начинается с 1 :) в нулевом байте хранится(по крайней мере в паскаль строках) - размер. Реализация отличается от нульконечных строк(pchar)

Comment: @Илья Посмотрите второе решение(еще один ответ на этот вопрос), там всё сделано на формуле для которой размер не важен, мой код просто пример одного из трюков как сократить кучу if then else

Comment: Я видел. Отличное решение, почему то автор его удалил. Успел себе сохранить.

Comment: @Илья Никто ничего не удалял, ответ перенесли в ваш вчерашний вопрос, там он больше к месту :)

Comment: С целью универсальности стоило бы ещё в условном операторе константы заменить на функции `Low()` и `High()`.

Comment: @Alekcvp тогда и массив динамический нужно делать, и выносить его из констант в параметры функции\метода, это не более чем пример как можно сокращать подобные монстроуозные конструкции, а как использовать пример - уже на совести автора кода а не примера :)